# Spring AOP proxy creation error with for bean uses spEL

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-el

I've the following bean definition:

```
<bean id="kenny" class="com.springinaction.spingidol.performers.Instrumentalist"
    p:song="'Disert Rose'" p:instrument="#{pianoInstrument}" />

<bean id="carl" class="com.springinaction.spingidol.performers.Instrumentalist"
    p:song="#{kenny.song?.toUpperCase()}" 
    p:instrument="#{kenny.song.contains('Rose')?saxophoneInstrument:harmonicaInstrument}"/>
```

Notice, the `carl`'s `instrument` property is being created based on `kenny`'s `song` property.

When run the my app it is **working perfectly** as long as I didn't use Spring AOP.

**BUT** when I add an aspect referring to the `carl` bean:

`<aop:before method="takeSeats" pointcut="execution(* com.springinaction.spingidol.performers.Performer.perform(..))"/>`

Where both `carl` and `kenny` beans implements the `Performer` interface, and hence I got the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carl' defined in class path resource [spring-idol.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 6): Property or field 'song' cannot be found on object of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.springinaction.spingidol.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 6): Property or field 'song' cannot be found on object of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1362)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.evaluate(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 6): Property or field 'song' cannot be found on object of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:215)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:85)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:78)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:54)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:84)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:153)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.Ternary.getValueInternal(Ternary.java:48)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:103)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:143)
    ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an expected behavior - what would happen is Spring would essentially create a dynamic proxy for the `kenny` bean, the dynamic proxy would be based on the `Perfomer` interface, which does not have a song property(no getters or setters for song) and hence the exception. A fix may be add getters for song into the `Performer` interface and that should cleanly work for you.

Comment: Aha, I got it. but I cannot add any implementation-specific methods in the interface. So, is there a common fix to this issue that doesn't affect my design badly?

Comment: I encountered the same problem while implementing code from the book Spring in Action. I was able to get past the error by creating an interface SongPerformer that extends Performer and having Instrumentalist implement SongPerformer. SongPerformer declares setSong and getSong.